# How to remove last character in String?

Tags: java

how to remove last word in a string
word should be dynamic
for example:-`String [] a={"100-muni-abc"};`
 i want output like this 100-muni 
remove last one-abe

Comment: have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
String a = "100-muni-abc";
String res = a.substring(0, a.lastIndexOf("-"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from

```
String str = "100-muni-abc";
```

Removing the last char

```
str = str.substring(0,str.length() - 1)
```

Removing the last 3 chars

```
str = str.substring(0,str.length() - 3)
```

A bit late huh?

Comment: Removing the last char should be str.length()-1

Comment: @radley I dont know what went to my mind there, you are right

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String str = "100-muni-abc";
String [] parts = str.split("-");
System.out.println(parts[0]+"-"+parts[1]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

1. String text = What is the name of your first love?;
2. String lastWord = text.substring(text.lastIndexOf(" ")+1);
3. System.out.println(lastWord);

Output Answer : love?